# xp:fileupload control and partial refresh in Chrome

Tags: xpages

My xp:fileupload control has stopped working in Chrome. It still works in Internet Explorer. Can it have something today with a recent update of Chrome?

When I run a full update instead of a partial refresh it works.

I do not get any error in the console or on the server.

The problem has starting to occur recently (incident reports).

I have Chrome v66.

Comment: FYI: File upload using partial refresh works in my Chrome 66 on Mac